# Advantage and Disadvantage of Partitioning by some of values of Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, performance, postgresql-performance

I'm going to implement/deploy a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE docref
(
    namespace  VARCHAR(50),
    key        VARCHAR(50),
    time_order INT,

    state      SMALLINT,
    hash       TEXT,
    uri        TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (namespace, key, time_order)
);
```

Almost all my queries use primary key to access / group by / sort data:

- `WHERE namspace = ? and created_at > ?`
- `WHERE namespace = ? and key = ?`
- `WHERE namespace = ? ... GRUOP BY namespace, key ... ORDER BY namespace, key`

I'm thinking to partition my table by `namespace` because:

- each `namespace` will containt a lot of data points (unpredictable and variable: 10k ~ 100m)
- all data points in each `namespace` are isolated and indepdendent from other partitions, which makes it a good choise
- I can prune partitions based on unwanted `namespace`s, and archive them easily

But I'm concerned that:

- the number of `namespace`s is not limited, > 5000
- the availabliltiy of each partition (`namespace`) is not limited; they can being used all the time for 2 or 3 years

Obviously it means that I'll end up with lots of tables which worries me.

Because I'm not experienced with Postgres, I'm looking to assess my reasining and concerns: Should I worry about the number of partitions and lifetime of each parition ? Are my concerns valid? In other word:

- Is it costly for Postgres to keep lots of (partitioned) tables avaiable?
- What about query planner?

Comment: What do you mean with "lots of open tables"? Keeping tables "available" does not really "cost" anything.

Comment: Indeed you should worry about the number of partitions, but with the improvements made in Postgres 11 5000 - 10000 partitions should be OK (even more so with the upcoming Postgres 12). The lifetime is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, can you provide some links/reference for me to read more about it? (about cost of open tables and new changes in Postgres 11 & 12)

Comment: Again: what do you mean with "open tables"? Tables aren't "opened", you just use them. For the performance improvements see the release notes for [postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html)  and [postgres 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html)

Comment: By "open" I'm trying to refer to "attached partitioned tables" and "runtime cost of each table" @a_horse_with_no_name